# How to get memory address of the FileDescriptor of mmap() function in Linux, for Video4Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory, yocto, video4linux

Good afternoon,

I am trying to determine the physical memory location of the buffer allocated by video for linux's IO_METHOD_MMAP

Looking through the mmap function,

```
    mmap(NULL /* start anywhere */,
                            buf.length,
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE /* required */,
                            MAP_SHARED /* recommended */,
                            fd, //FileDescriptor
                            buf.m.offset);
```

I see that buf.m.offset is 0, then increments the by the buf.length value for each plane.

What I am looking for is the physcial address in memory for the filedescriptor (fd) created by /dev/video0 device.

This is on Im6.

The purpose of this is to pass that physical address to the Gpu,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

After the successful `mmap` you could `open` (e.g. using `fopen`), then sequentially read (e.g. using `fgets`) the textual (pipe-like) `/proc/self/maps`  file (or also `/proc/self/smaps`).

See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108).