# Why proc process faster than others?

Tags: linux, proc

As we know there is some process which is faster than other. But I always wonder Why proc process faster than others?

Comment: Please do not say you are writing to proc. See answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

Confusion. The `/proc/` file system (read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) is indeed a pseudo-file system without real files on any hard disk. So reading it is quick (and could be faster than reading a file on a spinning hard disk). For example you could write some C code `fopen`-ing `/proc/self/maps`, looping on every line using `fgets`, and showing that line on your *stdout*, and finally `fclose`ing it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108).

On Linux `/proc/` is a convenient way to query the kernel about the operating system's state. You generally read (not write) pseudo-files from it.

Try also `cat /proc/$$/status` and `cat /proc/self/maps` in some terminal, and think a bit to understand the output.

BTW, if you want to do quickly some IO on files of reasonable size, put them on some [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) filesystem (which would be lost at shutdown time, and has some limitations).