# ulimit Linux connection limit

Tags: linux, ulimit

I have a question about `ulimit`:

```
ulimit -u unlimited
ulimit -n 60000
```

If I execute these in a screen, will they forever be kept as a setting on the screen until I kill the screen or do I have to run it every time I run the program?

What I want to do is irrelevant, I just want to know if they will be kept as a setting within the screen.

Comment: Are you referring to the [screen(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) utility in  your question, or to command windows?

Comment: yes I am referring to screen in linux that you can type screen -r nameofscreen

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5):

`ulimit` is a [bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). It invokes the [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) system call.

That syscall modifies some limit in its -shell- [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (likewise the `cd` builtin calls [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) and modifies the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of your shell process).

In a bash shell, [`$$` expands to the pid of that shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) process. So you can use `ps $$` (and even compose it, e.g. like in `touch /tmp/foo$$` or `cat /proc/$$/status`)

So the `ulimit` applies to your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and stay the same until you do another `ulimit` command (or until your shell terminates).

The limits of your shell process (and also its working directory) are inherited by every process started by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) from your shell. These processes include those running your commands in that same shell. Notice that changing the limit (or the working directory) of some process don't affect those of the parent process. Notice that [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) don't change limits or working directories.

**Limits** (and working directory) **are properties of *processes*** (not of terminals, screens, windows, etc...). Each process has **its own** : limits and working directory, [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) table, etc... You could use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to query them (try in some shell to run `cat /proc/self/limits` and `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `ls -l /proc/self/cwd /proc/self/fd/`). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069817/841108). Limits (and working directory) are inherited by child process started with [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) which has its own *copy* of them (so limits are not shared, but copied ... by `fork`).

But if you start another terminal window, it is running another shell process (which has its own limits and working directory).

See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html). Be sure to understand how [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) work, and how your shell uses them (for every command starting a new process, practically most of them).

You mention [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) in some comments. Be sure to read its `man` page (and every man page mentioned here!). Read also [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

A program can call by itself [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (or [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)) but that won't affect the limits (or working directory) of its parent process (often your shell). Of course it would affect future [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call))-ed [child processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) of the process running that program.

I recommend reading [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (a freely downloadable book about Linux programming) which has several chapters explaining all that. You need several books to explain the details.

After [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), read [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), be aware of existing [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), play with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and your own programs (writing a small shell is very instructive; or study the code of some existing one), and read perhaps *[Operating Systems: Three Easy pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)*.

NB. The [screen(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) utility manages several terminals, each having typically its shell process. I don't know if you refer to that utility. Read also about [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), and the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page.

---

The only way to really kill some screen is with a hammer, like this:
[image: breaking a screen with a hammer]

<sup>(image of a real hammer hitting a laptop found with Google, then cut with `gimp`, and put temporarily on my web server; the original URL is probably `https://www.istockphoto.com/fr/photo/femme-daffaires-stress%C3%A9-%C3%A0-lordinateur-crash-arrive-et-d%C3%A9truisent-le-moniteur-gm172788693-5836585` and I understand the license permits me to do that.)</sup>

Don't do that, you'll be sorry.

Apparently, you are talking of sending a *signal* (with [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) or [killall(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html) or [pkill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) to some *process* running the [screen(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) program, or to its [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). *It is not the same.*

Comment: Thank you for the big comment, but I am sorry to say that I am not very good in this field and its alot of this I dont understand, what I got a tip from a friend was to put ulimit -n 60000 and ulimit -c unlimited so my program dont restart when exceeding a userlimit of default of 1000. But without sounding condecending do you mind telling me if shell = screen and that aslong as i dont kill the screen, the settings remain? if it dont remain, where do you suggest me to put the limits without reseting? thanks and I hope you dont take offense to my answer

Comment: That is not a comment, but an answer. You need to read more about processes (and about `fork` and `execve`); I added reference to the ALP book, and you need to understand more about processes and shells

Comment: I am sorry, it is sure an answer but as I said, I don't understand that so good and I don't have the time to read in because this has to happen today. My question is pretty simple and that is all I want to know. I tried to disconnect from putty and enter the screen and the settings seemed to remain, but leaving the screen is default ulimit settings but in screen that i resume i have the settings i originally putted which is good, so I wonder if it will look for the screen settings for ulimit or the default root when leaving sceen

Comment: You need to spend several days reading more about processes and shells. I gave many links in my answer, but you need to do the learning job. It seems you don't understand what is a Unix process, and it takes time to understand that in full. I spent months on that in the late 1980-s. And explaining what exactly is a process takes several chapters of a book like ALP. I don't have the patience and the space to explain all that, you need to learn.

Comment: As long as `screen` keeps your shell process running, that shell keeps its limits, unless you change them with `ulimit`. Once that shell is gone, the limits don't exist (because they belong to the shell process)

Comment: Now I start to get it more, but can a shell process be gone and a screen remain? or does it only go away if a screen is killed?

Comment: You can terminate a shell process with `exit` builtin, or kill it with a command like `kill $$`. I'm confused by a "a screen is killed". Do you mean "a `screen` process is killed"? AFAIK, you can only kill processes (and related). I guess you are stil uneasy with the notion of process. You need to take time to read more about it.

Comment: what i mean with if a screen is killed is if i type the command killall screen, it will terminate all the screens i got available, then im pretty sure the ulimit will reset if i start a new screen, but i wonder if i dont kill the screen and changed the ulimit settings, is there any way the ulimits can reset if i dont kill the screen?

Comment: You don't kill screens. You might kill processes running (or started by) the  [screen(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) utility. It is not the same. You can kill other processes too.

Comment: And you are misunderstanding: `killall screen` is killing all the processes running  the `screen`  utility. AFAIK the only way of killing screens is to use a hammer on your own LCD display device (or laptop). Don't do that, you'll be sorry. The `kill` (and `killall`) command can only send signals to processes (and to process groups)

Comment: I spent a few minutes finding and cutting an image about killing screens. Do you understand that it is not the same as killing a process?