# how to use direct io write a small file with out extend file size

Tags: c++, c, file

How to use direct io write a small file with out change file size.

Assuming I have a file, file size is 1.1KB, I use direct io to read the file, and change some data, and write file......

see below

```cpp
//open file with O_DIRECT
handle_ = open("1.html", O_RDWR | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC | O_LARGEFILE,0777))

//file size is 1.1KB (i read 4KB)
pread64(handle_,buffer,4096,0);

memcpy(buffer,"11111",5);

//error (512b Aligned)
pwrite64(handle_,buffer,1.1KB,0);


//OK,but file size has been extended to 4KB 
pwrite64(handle_,buffer,4KB,0);
```

This is a real world problem because some software may use this file too, like webserver, it will get a wrong file size and response to client a bigger file.

(must be direct io, I have my reasons)

Comment: If this is a c++ program, why are you not using filestreams?

Comment: Here's an example of how to read the whole file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135248/how-to-load-a-wav-file-in-an-array-in-c/56136348#56136348 Writing it back is not much different. If the file is changed out of your control while you do this operation, you're out of luck.

Comment: Why do you use `O_LARGEFILE`?

Comment: "_must be direct io,i have my reasons_" - care to share those?

Comment: `pwrite64(handle_,buffer,1.1KB,0);`?!?  What is this?  Post your actual code.  You are checking the return values from `open()`, `pread()`, and `pwrite()`?

Comment: According to [open documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html): *'O_LARGEFILE: Allow files whose sizes cannot be represented in an off_t (but can be represented in an off64_t) to be opened.'* So at very first, not needed at all. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3425945/1312382), it shouldn't ever be used at all (and the proposed alternative is recommended in cited documentation as well). *Just a pure guess (!)*: using the flag might enforce 4K (or 512 at least, which 1.1k doesn't match either) block sizes. Have you tried without?

Comment: O_LARGEFILE  is a flag for support > 2GB file on 32-bit system,did not cause any problem,i am sure .

Answer (score 2):

> how to use direct io write a small file with out extend file size

Sorry, you can't - `O_DIRECT` requires the I/O you do to be 512 byte aligned. Assuming `KB` is 1024 bytes, `1.1 * 1024 = 1126.4` (which is a strange number because it won't be a whole byte) so you would have to round that up to `1536` to use `O_DIRECT` thus causing extension.

Your options are limited to:

- Do the `O_DIRECT` write then truncate the file to the correct size (it sounds like this is what you wound up doing).
- Write only full block multiples of the file using `O_DIRECT` then write the last little bit using a non-`O_DIRECT` write.

If both of these sound awful then I can only point you towards [@ted-lyngmo's request for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305878/how-to-use-direct-io-write-a-small-file-with-out-extend-file-size#comment101105046_57305878):

> "must be direct io,i have my reasons" - care to share those?

`O_DIRECT` comes with heavy usage rules...

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use [mapping file into memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), in unix its [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall.
Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604431/why-we-can-mmap-to-a-file-but-exceed-the-file-size) answer

Comment: If OP insists on direct I/o, there's a warning in the man page about mixing it with mmap.

Comment: thanks ,but mmap with direct io is not a good idea for me,now i'm using a stupid solution like this : after call pwrite64, i use ftruncate64 method to reset file size to 1.1Kb