# Is there a go command equivalent to ps?

Tags: linux, go

I want a way to iterate through a list of PIDs scanning for processes with a particular command. For example the columns of `ps ax` are

```
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
```

I was wondering if there was a way for me to determine the `COMMAND` column of a PID given its number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go language and the `ps` command are unrelated.

The `ps` command is part of POSIX specification, and available on all Unix-like systems (including Linux, Solaris, *BSD, ....). Read [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html). It is related to your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (and you probably don't have it on Windows). Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more about OSes, and some Linux programming book like [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) to learn more about Linux programming. See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (and find the Go equivalent of them).

> I want a way to iterate through a list of PIDs scanning for processes with a particular command.
>
> I was wondering if there was a way for me to determine the COMMAND column of a PID given its number.

This is unrelated to Go. You could use the `/proc/` pseudo file system, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), which exists on all Linux systems, both with and without Go installed on them. `/proc/` is internally used by [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), etc...

To iterate on the list of processes (on Linux), you need to read the `/proc/` directory for numerical entries (e.g. `/proc/1234/` exists if there is a process of pid 1234). To read a directory, use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) in C and they all have their Go equivalent e.g. in [`ioutils` package](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/).

In particular, for process 1234, you could read `/proc/1234/cmdline` (which contains <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte separated strings). Of course you could read that file from some Go program. Try the `od -cx /proc/self/cmdline` command (using [od(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html)) to understand the format of that file ...

Pseudofiles in `/proc/` are "pipe-like", have an apparent size (as given by [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or by [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)...) of 0, and should be read sequentially, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108).

Answer (score 1):

[go-ps](https://github.com/mitchellh/go-ps) may be useful for you if you want to do it in a portable way.