# Why doesn't time() from time.h have a syscall to sys_time?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, glibc

I wrote a very simple program with calls `time()` to illustrate the use of`strace`, but I'm having a problem; the `time()` call doesn't seem to actually produce a syscall!

I ended up stepping into the `time()` function in GDB and now I'm more confused than ever. From the disassembly of the `time()` function:

```
0x7ffff7ffad90 <time>:  push   rbp
0x7ffff7ffad91 <time+1>:    test   rdi,rdi
0x7ffff7ffad94 <time+4>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffffd30d]        # 0x7ffff7ff80a8
0x7ffff7ffad9b <time+11>:   mov    rbp,rsp
0x7ffff7ffad9e <time+14>:   je     0x7ffff7ffada3 <time+19>
0x7ffff7ffada0 <time+16>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rdi],rax
0x7ffff7ffada3 <time+19>:   pop    rbp
0x7ffff7ffada4 <time+20>:   ret
```

How is this function actually getting the current time if it does not call the kernel? Its flow is:

- Prologue
- Get some value from `(0x7ffff7ffad94 + 0xffffffffffffd30d)` (`0x7ffff7ff80a8`) and put it in rax (to be returned)
- Check if rdi (first argument) was null
- If not put the value in rax (return value) there also
- Epilogue

This makes sense with the functionality of `time()`; if the argument is null, it just returns the value, but if not it also puts it in the argument. The question I have is, where is it getting the time value? What's so magical about address `0x7ffff7ff80a8`, and how does it do this without a syscall?

I'm using GCC 6.3.0 and Ubuntu GLIBC 2.24-9ubuntu2.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Probably your call to [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) uses the [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) (maybe via [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) or via `__vdso_time`). If [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) is used,

> When tracing systems calls with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), symbols (system calls)
> that are exported by the vDSO will *not* appear in the trace output.

Details could be kernel and libc specific (and of course architecture specific).

For similar [vDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) reasons, `strace date` don't show any time-related syscalls.

And vDSO is a really handy feature (subject to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). Thanks to it, timing calls (e.g. [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)...) go really quick (about 40 nanoseconds on my i5-4690S). AFAIU, no [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) (or user to kernel [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) transition) is happening.

So your `0x7ffff7ff80a8` is probably sitting in the vDSO (and the kernel ensures it contains the current time). You might check by using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (e.g. [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108) and showing `/proc/self/maps` from your program), or perhaps using [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) and [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html)

Comment: That's right, no kernel/user transition.  The VDSO pages are code + data that the kernel maps into the address-space of every process, at a fixed address.  User-space (specifically glibc's wrappers for the some system calls like `time`, `getpid`, etc) simply runs a regular near-`call` instruction to call a function in the VDSO page.  The reason the kernel provides user-space code for them is that they normally never need to enter the kernel at all, just read from the read-only page where the kernel exports scale factors for RDTSC, and the process's PID.

Comment: On x86 in 32-bit mode, the recommended way to make fast system calls is by calling into the VDSO: If `sysenter` is available, it has the code for the user-space side of the `sysenter` dance that provides the kernel with an EIP to return to, or it uses AMD 32-bit `syscall`, or it falls back to `int 0x80`.  (The kernel chooses what to put in the VDSO page it exports based on boot-time CPU detection.)  But in 64-bit x86 user-space, glibc uses `syscall` directly, because the `syscall` instruction is baseline for x86-64.

Comment: Oops, actually the VDSO pages can be ASLRed; the functions aren't at fixed addresses.  The exported pages have ELF headers, so the runtime dynamic linker takes care of things, just like if the VDSO was a shared library mapped from a disk file.  (The kernel writes the VDSO base address somewhere the dynamic linker can find it.)  See https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/#virtual-system-calls.