# fork() and execve() efficiency

Tags: linux, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

In terms of memory allocation efficiency is it right to say that after a `fork()` in the code of the child if I execute a program with `execve()` this would be more efficient than the same program executed without `execve()` because the child won't have allocated the stack and heap of the father but only is own?

Naife example:

without execve

```
 [..some father code...]
int i;
if(!fork()) {
 sum() //from an #include "porg.h"
}
```

with execve

```
 [..some father code...]

if(!fork()) {
 execve("sum", NULL, NULL); //sum is a program which executes i=2+3
}
```

The second in terms of memory allocation is better?
Is it better to replace the entire virtual address space of my process or it is better to get running the mentioned code with a call to a function in another program which is included with #include "prog" in terms of number of number of operations done by the so and in terms of the memory carried behind during the execution of the program?

Comment: Please define what you mean by `memory`. I'm understanding it as [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). So **edit your question** to improve it. It currently is unclear. If possible, provide some [MCVE]

Comment: This makes no sense - how can it possibly be cheaper (in terms of either CPU or memory) to execute a whole different program than a single instruction?! After all, *both* code snippets invoke `fork()`, and the second one does much much more.

Comment: Please define what you mean by *efficient* in **memory allocation efficiency**.

Comment: @wallyk edited hope its clear

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully some book on Linux or POSIX programming, perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf). Read also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

**After a successful `execve`, the entire [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has been replaced and reinitialized** , according to the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable that was executed (see [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html); so `execve` does not return except on failure).

So your `sum` program don't see anything from the previous program executing it (except the mandatory `argv` & `environ`, which get *copied* by `execve`). BTW, your usage of `execve` is wrong. You should provide some `argv` array, and some `environ` array (both should be non-null, the `argv` should be non-empty, and both should end with a `NULL` string)... You often would prefer some [exec*(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) function.

And after a successful `fork` both (child and father) processes have their own virtual address space (initially, nearly identical *copies*). BTW, your code forgot to check failure of `fork`.

> The second in terms of memory allocation is better?

So that question has no sense. The entire "memory" -actually, virtual address space- has been reset and reinitialized (and that includes the call stack and the heap).

You can explore the virtual address space of your process by using `/proc/`. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Try `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/self/maps` to get a better intuition about virtual address space.

Play also with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) done by some program or process. Try for example `strace date` (and see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48252567/841108)).

> than the same program executed without execve()

That is impossible, since **`execve` is the *only* way to execute a program** (except of course [`init`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), today called [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) - see [init(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/init.1.html), which gets started magically by the kernel at boot time; and some few other weird kernel initiated processes....)

Comment: than the same program executed without execve() : for program i meant code sorry, for memory allocation efficiency i meant : Is it better to replace the entire virtual address space of my process or it is better to get running the mentioned code with a call to a function in another program which is included with #include "prog", in terms of number of operations by the so and in terms of the memory carried behind during the execution of the program?

Comment: Please edit your question (e.g. improve it a lot and provide some [MCVE]), don't comment my answer. I still don't understand what you mean (and I'm guessing your don't understand what `fork` & `execve` do, and what is a virtual address space, or a process). I don't understand what should be *better* than what?