# How to recover all current processes on linux

Tags: c++, linux

I need to recover all running processes using c ++ and under linux. But I don't find lib or corresponding functions.

I can't run a linux command such as "ps".

Comment: By "recover" you mean "list" or "enumerate", I presume?

Comment: Yes, in order to get all informations about currents PIDS.

Comment: If you just want to enumerate processes, the `/proc` filesystem is your friend. But, it's really unclear *exactly* what you are asking.

Comment: sounds like you have messed up your PATH variable. do this ; `saveBadPATH="$PATH" ; export PATH="/usr/bin;bin". Now ps` should work. You may need to add other elements to PATH, so `export PATH="/other/missing/path:$PATH"` etc. YOu `echo "$saveBadPATH" and if  you see other elements to add, be sure that any element include a space char is added with syntax above, using dbl-quotes. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: @JesperJuhl : This is my interpretation of what O.P. means by 'I can't run a linux command such as "ps"', coupled with the word "Recover" in the title. As it is a poorly written Q, I think more than one set of eyes on the problem is the reasonable approach to helping get a solution. Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter if the path is messed up that badly; then it's likely a good time to log out and start a new session ;)

Comment: @shellter I like how following your advice would completely break `PATH`. Also, how is this C++ related?

Comment: @shellter *I* read it as "OP wants to get a list of all currently running processes (and details about them) from code and running `system("ps")` is not an option". But yes, the question is *really* unclear.

Comment: @melpomene : Yes I re-read my comment, and it should be `export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin"`. Sorry for that. Until we understand what specfically the OP is trying to accomplish, I'll leave my comment in place. If @JeperJuhl interpretation is correct, then I'll be happy to remove my comments. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(I'm guessing that you need to *inspect*, *scan*, *list*, or *discover* processes; recovering processes is a difficult thing, read about [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing))</sup>

You should consider using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), that is the `/proc/` filesystem (Linux specific).

The process of pid 1234 is described by the `/proc/1234/` directory. Try `ls /proc/$$/` in a terminal.

So you can explore processes by using appropriate calls (e.g. [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) etc....) on the `/proc/`  file tree (and this is what `ps`, `top` etc.. are using; check with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) ...).

Beware that many *files* under `/proc/` have a 0 size as given by [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) but are sequentially readable (a bit like a pipe). Try for example `stat /proc/$$/status` then `cat /proc/$$/status`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108).