# How to find the number of data mapped by mmap()?

Tags: mmap

if mmap() was used to read a file, how can I find the number of data mapped by mmap().

```
float *map = (float *)mmap(NULL, FILESIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Comment: You don't understand what `mmap` is doing. Please read more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mmap` [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) does not read data. It just maps the data in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (by indirectly configuring your [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)), and that virtual address space is changed by a successful `mmap`. Later, your program will read that data (or not). In your example, your program might later read `map[356]` if `mmap` has succeeded (and you should test against its failure).

Read carefully the documentation of [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). The second argument (in your code, `FILESIZE`) defines the size of the mapping (in bytes). You might check that it is a multiple of `sizeof(float)` and divide it by `sizeof(float)` to get the number of elements in `map` that are meaningful and obtained from the file. The size of the mapping is rounded up to a multiple of pages. The `man` page of [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) says:

> A file is mapped in multiples of the page size.  For a file that is
>          not a multiple of the page size, the remaining memory is zeroed when
>          mapped, and writes to that region are not written out to the file.

Data is mapped in [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)). A page is usually 4096 bytes. Read more about [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

The page size is returned by [getpagesize(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) or by [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) with `_SC_PAGESIZE` (which usually gives 4096).

Consider reading some book like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable) to understand how [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) works and what is a [memory mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

On Linux, the `/proc/` filesystem (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) is very useful to understand the virtual address space of some process: try `cat /proc/$$/maps` in your terminal, and read more to understand its output. For a process of pid 1234, try also `cat /proc/1234/maps`

From inside your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), you could even read sequentially the `/proc/self/maps` pseudo-file to understand its virtual address space, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108).

Comment: so how can i find the number of data being mapped by mmap. Thank you!

Comment: It is the second argument to `mmap` rounded up to the page size. You might divide that by `sizeof(float)` in your case to get the number of elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand data is mapped in pages. For example, if the file I'm trying to map is only of 3000 bytes, after data is mapped, it will round up to one page. The rest part of page is not used.So how do I know the size of those "valid" data from the original file.

Comment: My answer and comment explained that. Please take time to read them more carefully. Read also the *Operating Systems: Three Eeasy Pieces* book... It seems you don't understand how virtual memory works and what is a virtual address space. I gave references, but an entire book is needed to explain that. You should spend a few days reading it.

Comment: ... your main issue is to understand what is virtual memory and what is the virtual address space of some process. You need to read books about these. That takes days. We don't have enough space on StackOverflow to write books.

Comment: Perfect answer, very detailed with a lot of additional info! +1