# When is heap memory prefered over stack memory

Tags: c++, stack, stack-overflow, heap-memory

I know that local arrays are created on the stack, and have automatic storage duration, since they are destroyed when the function they're in ends. They necessarily have a fixed size:

```
{
   int foo[16];
}
```

Arrays created with operator `new[]` have dynamic storage duration and are stored on the heap. They can have varying sizes.

```
{
    const int size = 16;
    int* foo = new int[size];
    // do something with foo
    delete[] foo;
}
```

The size of the stack is fixed and limited for every process.

My question is: 
**Is there a rule of thumb when to switch from stack memory to heap memory, in order to reduce the stack memory consumption?**

Example:

- `double a[2]` is perfectly reasoable;
- `double a[1000000000]` will most likely result in a stack overflow, if the stack size is `1mb`

Where is a reasonable limit to switch to dynamic allocation?

Comment: Very close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48952362/841108) and my answer there

Comment: Rule of thumb: if it fits on the stack, allocated them on the stack (local variable), if it's too big to fit on the stack, allocate dynamically.

Comment: First of all I would rather recommend [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain arrays, or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of your own dynamic allocation. Then as for the "break point" where one should start using `std::vector` instead of `std::array`, that really depends on the use-case. The "rule of thumb" is that the element counter is "small enough", but how small that "small enough" is, is not something that can be generally advised.

Comment: For stack-allocated array, you need to know its size at _compile time_. In practice, size of data structures is usually not known until _runtime_. (_Small buffer optimization_ can be of your interest if you want to dig deeper into the problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952648/841108) for a discussion about heap allocation.

> Where is a reasonable limit to switch to dynamic allocation?

In several cases, including:

- too large [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable). As a rule of thumb, I recommend avoiding call frames of more than a few kilobytes (and a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of more than a megabytes). That limit might be increased if you are sure that your function is not usable recursively. On many small embedded systems, the stack is much more limited (e.g. to a few kilobytes) so you need to limit even more each call frame (e.g. to only a hundred bytes). BTW, on some systems, you can increase the call stack limit much more (perhaps to several gigabytes), but this is also a sysadmin issue.
- non LIFO allocation discipline, which happens quite often.

Notice that most C++ standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) allocate their data in the heap, even if the container is on the stack. For example, an automatic variable of [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) type, e.g. a local `std::vector<double> autovec;` has its data heap allocated (and released when the vector is [destroyed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming))). Read more about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).