# Optimal Way of Using mlockall() for Real-time Application (nanosecond sensitive)

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, system

I am reading mlockall()'s manpage: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html

It mentions

```
Real-time processes that are using mlockall() to prevent delays on page 
faults should reserve enough locked stack pages before entering the time-
critical section, so that no page fault can be caused by function calls.  This 
can be achieved by calling a function that allocates a sufficiently large 
automatic variable (an array) and writes to the memory occupied by this array in 
order to touch these stack pages.  This way, enough pages will be mapped for the 
stack and can be locked into RAM.  The dummy writes ensure that not even copy-
on-write page faults can occur in the critical section.
```

I am a bit confused by this statement:

```
This can be achieved by calling a function that allocates a sufficiently large 
automatic variable (an array) and writes to the memory occupied by this array in 
order to touch these stack pages.
```

All the automatic variables (variables on stack) are created "on the fly" on the stack when the function is called.  So how can I achieve what the last statement says?

For example, let's say I have this function:

```
void foo() {
char a;
uint16_t b;
std::deque<int64_t> c;
// do something with those variables
}
```

Or does it mean before I call any function, I should call a function like this in main():

```
void reserveStackPages() {
int64_t stackPage[4096/8 * 1024 * 1024];
memset(stackPage, 0, sizeof(stackPage));
}
```

If yes, does it make a difference if I first allocate the stackPage variable on heap, write and then free?  Probably yes, because heap and stack are 2 different region in the RAM?

std::deque exists above is just to bring up another related question -- what if I want to reserve memory for things using both stack pages and heap pages.  Will calling "heap" version of reserveStackPages() help?

The goal is to minimize all the jitters in the application (yes, I know there are many other things to look at such as TLB miss, etc; just trying to deal with one kind of jitter at once, and slowly progressing into all).

Thanks in advance.

P.S.  This is for a low latency trading application if it matters.

Comment: What kind of application are you coding? Please edit your question to explain that. Are you sure you want `mlockall` ?

Comment: Even with the edit, you are not explaining what kind of application you are coding. "real-time" does not means much. Is it some network filter, is it some robot vision program? And nano-second sensitive is not meaningful and is certainly an illusion (because of caches misses)

Comment: I finally downvoted your question, because you still don't give enough context and don't explain what kind of application you are coding. I will revert my downvote when you'll explain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't need to use `mlockall`, unless you code (more or less hard) real-time applications (I actually never used it).

If you do need it, you'll better code in C (not in genuine C++) the most real-time parts of your code, because you surely want to understand the details of memory allocation. Notice that unless you dive into `std::deque` *implementation*, you don't exactly know where it is sitting (probably most of the data is heap allocated, even if your `c` is an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)).

You should first understand *in details* the virtual address space of your process. For that, [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) is useful: from inside your process, you'll read `/proc/self/maps` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108)), from outside (e.g. some terminal) you'll do `cat /proc/1234/maps` for a process of pid 1234. Or use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html).

> because heap and stack are 2 different regions in the RAM?

In fact, your process' address space contains many segments (listed in `/proc/1234/maps`), much more that two. Typically every dynamically linked shared library (such as `libc.so`) brings a few segments.

Try `cat /proc/self/maps` and `cat /proc/$$/maps` in your terminal to get a better intuition about virtual address spaces. On my machine, the first gives 19 segments of the `cat` process -each displayed as a line- and the second  97 segments of the `zsh` (my shell) process.

To ensure that your stack has enough space, you indeed could call a function allocating a large enough automatic variable, like your `reserveStackPages`. Beware that call stacks are practically of limited size (a few megabytes usually, see also [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)).

If you really need `mlockall` (which is unlikely) you might consider linking statically your program (to have less segments in your virtual address space).

Look also into [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) (and perhaps [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html)). It is generally much more useful than `mlockall`. BTW, in practice, most of your virtual memory is in RAM (unless your system experiments [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)), and then you'll see it immediately).

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand the role of [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

PS. Nano-second sensitive applications does not make much sense (because of [cache misses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#CACHE-MISS) that the software does not control).

Comment: haha, yes, nanosecond actually doesn't make much sense.  But what I am trying to do is to minimize jitters in terms of latency in the application.  And some of the applications at work are migrated into FPGA to avoid all jitter.

Comment: That should go into the question, and you still need to explain what kind of application you are coding. Nanoseconds-sensitive & C++ containers are not compatible.

Comment: Yes, using C++ containers might trigger jitters (as it is implementation specific and likely to use heap for allocating elements).  I on purpose put it there so that I want to see how people think about the optimal use of mlockall() for a container on the stack as the container will use stack pages as well as (likely) heap pages.