# How to identify memory consumption per thread in a process?

Tags: multithreading, memory, ps

A multi-thread process written in C exhausts almost all of system memory. To find out the thread which is consuming most of the memory, I made a core file using `gcore [pid]` to check the memory usage per threads, but I can't find the way to do that.

`ps -eLFlm` and top command with *-H* option shows the total memory consumption, but not per thread.

Is there any useful tip to solve the problem?

OS : Centos6

Comment: Try `$ ps -T -p <pid>`

Comment: Are you sure about this statement _To find out the thread who consuming the memory_ ? That there are indeed multiple threads spawn off in your process.

Comment: ps -T -p <pid> does not show memory information. It shows PID of threads. Process I want to examine has 18 threads including LWP.

Comment: What is your program doing? How long does it runs before exhausting system memory? How big is it (hundred thousands lines of C)? What libraries are you using? All these details are important, so you'll better [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52601090/edit) your question and provide some motivation and context!

Answer (score 3):

> A multi-thread process written in C exhausts almost all of system memory. To find out the thread which is consuming most of the memory....

That question does not make sense. By definition, all threads of the same process share the same [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). You could query it programmatically using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (e.g. [reading `/proc/self/maps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108) from your program).

It is possible (and quite common) that some heap memory is allocated (e.g. with `malloc`) in thread A, and would be released (e.g. `free`-d) later in some other thread B (often the main thread, just before exiting).

The C [dynamic memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) heap is, *by definition*, a whole program property.

A typical example is the last `arg` argument to [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). It generally should be heap-allocated. You could document and adopt the convention that the calling thread (the one using `pthread_create`) would `malloc` it, but that the created thread should `free` it (you could require that each `start_routine` passed to `pthread_create` should `free` that `arg`).

> Is there any useful tip to solve the problem?

Perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) might help you finding your [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You'll better compile all your program (and perhaps some relevant libraries) with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information (e.g. compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -g`) then restart your program. But such bugs are difficult to find, so be prepared to spend several weeks on them.

---

From the conceptual point of view, the "theory" of [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (and also [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), perhaps [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), etc...) could be helpful. So read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) (it is introducing the good concepts and terminology, and it explains that memory management is a whole program issue). A lot of concepts there are even relevant for programs in non-GC-ed languages like C or C++.

You need to **define and follow some good enough *whole program conventions* regarding memory management** (and that is difficult).